# Finding $\lim_{x\to \infty} e^{\bigl( x+\frac{1}{x} \bigr)}- e^x$ by L'Hôpital's Rule

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am unable to evaluate this limit:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} e^{\bigl( x+\frac{1}{x} \bigr)}- e^x$$
I tried to solve by L'Hôpital's rule, but I am ending nowhere. The  steps are obvious, so I am not re-writing them here. Graphically, this should go to infinity. I tried a few online calculators too, but those were without steps.  Please help out.

EDIT: My steps:

1. $\frac{e^{1/x}-1}{e^-x}$
2. $\frac{e^(x +1/x)}{x^2}$
3. $e^{\bigl( x+\frac{1}{x} \bigr)} \frac{x^2-1}{2x^3}$

I am unable to get rid of the term: $e^{x + 1/x}$

Comment: What did you end up with after a few obvious steps? People may help you to go on if you show them the steps.

Comment: I could not get rid of the term $e^(x+1/x)$

Comment: Use $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$.

Comment: @DiegoMath I did the same.

Comment: By the way, why do you want to apply l'Hôpital's rule here? Doesn't Taylor's formula for $x\mapsto e^{\frac{1}{x}}$ work?

Comment: @Nicolas I am not aware of this approach. Please elaborate if possible.

Comment: You should not have the $n$ terms in your calculation.

Comment: Just use the simple approach $e^u>1+u$ in zero neighbourhood. You are left with $\frac{e^x}{x}$ limit which I think you can handle.

Comment: @mrsamy thank you, it was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT (for the use of Hôpital's rule)

$$e^{\bigl( x+\frac{1}{x} \bigr)}- e^x=e^x(e^{1\over x}-1)=\frac{e^{1\over x}-1}{e^{-x}}$$

---

EDIT

Compute $$\begin{aligned}\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}e^{\bigl( x+\frac{1}{x} \bigr)}- e^x&=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{e^{1\over x}-1}{e^{-x}}=\\\\&=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{e^x}{x^2}\cdot e^{1\over x}\end{aligned}$$
Now, use

- $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}e^{1\over x}=e^0=1$
- $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{e^x}{x^2}=\infty$ (repeated use of l'Hôpital's rule)

Comment: HR stands for ?

Comment: Hints should be put in the comments. In fact, this hint was put in the comments 9 minutes before you posted.

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha It is now edited in my solution.

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha I completed my solution. Is it now fine for you?

Comment: Thank you, I got my glitch.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat indirect approach: since$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{1/x}-1}{1/x}=\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{e^y-1}{y}=\lim_{y\to0^+}e^y=1$$by L'Hôpital's rule (or even just the definition of $\left.(e^z)^\prime\right|_{z=0}$),$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(e^{x+1/x}-e^x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^x=\infty.$$